# How can I breakout a fixed position element from it's parent?

Tags: css

I have a fixed position element. I want it position on the bottom and to take up 100% of the screen width.  It keeps taking the width of it's parent from the center.  The blue container starts from the locatino of the red instead of the view port.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 800px; background-color: red; height: 1500px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; z-index: 999">


<div style="background-color: blue; width: 100%; height: 350px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; z-index: 9999">

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got code you can share? Fixed elements by the way are positioned wrt to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you mean.
But you can located the blue element in abetter way.

```
.blue{
     position:fixed;
     height:350px;

     /*make 100% width*/
     left:0;
     right:0;

     bottom:0;    
}
```